# SwiftUI: How to update passing array item in the other view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to update arrays item with typed new value into Textfield, but List is not updated with edited value.

***My Code is:***

**Model:**

```swift
    struct WalletItem: Identifiable{

        let id = UUID()
        var name:String
        var cardNumber:String
        var type:String
        var cvc:String
        let pin:String
        var dateOfExpiry:String
    }
```

ModelView:

```swift
    class Wallet: ObservableObject{

        @Published var wallets = [
            WalletItem(name: "BSB", cardNumber: "123456789", type: "master card", cvc: "1234", pin: "1234", dateOfExpiry: "2016-06-29"),
            WalletItem(name: "Alpha bank", cardNumber: "123456789", type: "master card", cvc: "1234", pin: "1234", dateOfExpiry: "2017-03-12"),
            WalletItem(name: "MTБ", cardNumber: "123456789", type: "master card", cvc: "1234", pin: "1234", dateOfExpiry: "2020-11-12"),
        ]

    }
```

**First View:**

```swift
    struct WalletListView: View {

        // Properties
        // ==========

        @ObservedObject var wallet = Wallet()
        @State var isNewItemSheetIsVisible = false


        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List(wallet.wallets) { walletItem in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditWalletItem(walletItem: walletItem)){
                            Text(walletItem.name)
                        }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Cards", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading: Button(action: { self.isNewItemSheetIsVisible = true
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            Text("Add item")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isNewItemSheetIsVisible) {
                NewWalletItem(wallet: self.wallet)
            }
        } 

    }
```

and **Secondary View:**

```swift
    struct EditWalletItem: View {

        @State var walletItem: WalletItem


        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

        var body: some View {
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Card Name")){
                    TextField("", text: $walletItem.name)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
                {
                    Text("Back")
                }, trailing:
                Button(action: {

                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
                {
                    Text("Save")
            })

        }

    }
```

P.S: If I use @Binding instead of the @State I've got an error in the first view: Initializer `init(_:)` requires that `Binding<String>` conform to `StringProtocol`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are modified parts (tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2):

1. Sure over binding

```
struct EditWalletItem: View {
    @Binding var walletItem: WalletItem
```

2. Place to pass it

```
List(Array(wallet.wallets.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (i, walletItem) in
    NavigationLink(destination: EditWalletItem(walletItem: self.$wallet.wallets[i])){
       Text(walletItem.name)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ForEach(Array(list.enumerated()))` will only work correctly if the list is an Array but not for an ArraySlice, and it has the downside of copying the list.

A better approach is using a `.indexed()` helper:

```swift
struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)
    let base: Base
    var startIndex: Index { self.base.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { self.base.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        self.base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        self.base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        self.base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: self.base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}
```

Example:

[image]

```swift
// SwiftUIPlayground
// https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Position {
    var id = UUID()
    var count: Int
    var name: String
}

class BookingModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var positions: [Position]

    init(positions: [Position] = []) {
        self.positions = positions
    }

}

struct EditableListExample: View {

    @ObservedObject var bookingModel = BookingModel(
        positions: [
            Position(count: 1, name: "Candy"),
            Position(count: 0, name: "Bread"),
        ]
    )

    var body: some View {
        // >>> Passing a binding into an Array via index:
        List(bookingModel.positions.indexed(), id: \.element.id) { i, _ in
            PositionRowView(position: self.$bookingModel.positions[i])
        }
    }
}

struct PositionRowView: View {

    @Binding var position: Position

    var body: some View {
        Stepper(
            value: $position.count,
            label: {
                Text("\(position.count)x \(position.name)")
            }
        )
    }

}

struct EditableListExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditableListExample()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How does the Apple-suggested .indexed() property work in a ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230978/how-does-the-apple-suggested-indexed-property-work-in-a-foreach)