# How does the Apple-suggested .indexed() property work in a ForEach?

Tags: swiftui

In the release notes to iOS 13 Apple said:

*The Binding structure’s conditional conformance to the Collection protocol is removed. (51624798)*. And then suggested iterating through arrays this way:

```
var body: some View {
        List(landmarks.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { (index, landmark) in
            Toggle(landmark.name, isOn: self.$landmarks[index].isFavorite)
        }
    }
```

But you also need to implement this:

```
struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)

    let base: Base

    var startIndex: Index { base.startIndex }

    var endIndex: Index { base.startIndex } // Possibly this should be endIndex?

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}
```

So first of all there appears to be a typo on line 6: that might need to be changed to `base.endIndex` but **it doesn't work either way**. It's a shame because it looks like a neat way to iterate with both element and index. So, is there a mistake I am making in how I'm implementing it?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI


let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height


struct SingleBall: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var position = CGPoint.zero
    var isDeleting = false
}

class BallStorage: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var balls: [SingleBall] = [
        
        SingleBall(position: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 220)),
        SingleBall(position: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 120)),
        SingleBall(position: CGPoint(x: 200, y:160)),
        SingleBall(position: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
        
    ]
    
}


struct StartScreen: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var ballStorage = BallStorage()
    @State var isDeleting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
            
            ZStack {  // stack of balls
                
            
                ForEach(ballStorage.balls.indexed(), id: \.1.id) {
                
              (number, item) in
            
                    littleBall(
                        ballStorage: ballStorage,
                        numberInArray: number )
                
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight) //end stack balls
        

            
        
    }
    
}
```

Littleball is a thing that just displays a black circle. So when I am doing the same thing by iterating over indices, four circles get rendered nicely (but looking for alternative way because you can't delete things from the array with indices).
With the above code nothing gets rendered. Why?

EDIT: To clarify, the .indexed() implementation is obviously also in the scope of the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `.indexed()` does work:

```swift
struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)
    let base: Base
    var startIndex: Index { self.base.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { self.base.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        self.base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        self.base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        self.base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: self.base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}
```

- [Full example and more information](https://www.ralfebert.de/swiftui/mutating-foreach/)

Comment: Could you clarify what the fundamental issue was with the OP's code?